# CSS to Correct Apostrophe for Digital Publishing

Tags: html, css

You can use incorrect coding like the popular (sic) *right single close-quote* `&rsquo;` to replace system default that is `&prime;`: however, this does not create publishing standard apostrophe (details on that below).
Alternatively, there could be a way to force correct `&apos;` using CSS and thereby avoid hand coding an incorrect replacement punctuation:

1. Could CCS solution involve something like `body["'"] {`?
2. Anyone know how to handle all langs with one stylesheet (with a solution to this problem)?
3. Must publisher app be installed (where? how?), for correct `&apos;` display in browser?

Please answer these questions without using examples of incorrect coding.
If you have some answers, jump right in.
My questions arise using an English Keyboard in Region 3 (Americas).
The `:lang` and `keyboard` references at MSDN got me thinking maybe Region might affect my problem coding standard publishing apostrophes, so I mention that here.
Generally, can CSS correct for publishing the incorrectly displayed `&apos;`, with system and typography otherwise enforcing incorrect `&prime;`? If that sounds silly, read on.

**some nasty details**
Both HTML `&prime;` (CSS `\2032`) and HTML `&apos;` (CSS `\0027`) use the same glyph in every font installed by operating system. Even where the `body {font}` contains a somewhat decorative flat prime, the system displays an ugly system font flat prime. HTML CSS code for correct apostrophe punctuation for publishing is ignored as a system inclusion by W3 for decades, so adapt. How? As I see it, coders must use incorrect math prime `&prime;` for all digital publishing, or equally incorrect single close-quote `&rsquo;` by manual hand coding each apostrophe. However, all Apple and Microsoft operating system fonts replace `&apos;` hand coded instruction with `&prime;` font display in the local browser, as the system provides no typographic alternative. Installed Word processors correct this mistake easily, since all system dictionaries are programmed to use apostrophe correctly, for the word processing community. However, for web designers and developers, coding tools and system browsers are all programmed to support the `&prime;` flood, regardless of having a Word Processor installed. On Apple devices the only exception to complete avoidance of correct apostrophe, is the Hebrew-only font Raanana (which does not display with English Keyboard).

The following CSS bypass only corrects `quotes`. Coders must manually correct `apostrophes` one-by-one. Some flat quotes might be intended so an editor's global 'replace' of '`'`' [*'replace' flat quotes intended as addressing machine behavior here*] might remove punctuation that is intended to use default flat `&prime;`. The same dilemma facing 'replace' also seems to hinder the CSSS solution. Anyway, here's the bypass (which is not a solution, as it does not touch the underlying problem).

```
body:lang(en) > q { quotes: '\201C' '\201D' '\2018' '\2019'; }
body:lang(fr) > q { quotes: '« ' ' »'; }
body:lang(de) > q { quotes: '»' '«' '\2039' '\203A'; }
blockquote { quotes: '\201c' '\201d'; } blockquote:before { content: open-quote; font-family: 'Times', serif; } blockquote:after  { content: close-quote; font-family: 'Times', serif; }
q { quotes: '\2018' '\2019'; } q:before { content: open-quote; font-family: 'Times', serif; } q:after  { content: close-quote; font-family: 'Times', serif; }
```

Problems with the suggested CSS bypass:

• In addition to `html:lang`, the `:after` and `:before` pseudos are `lang` specific
• Request: OSX-IOS-PC-AD English apostrophe 'key'
   response: how many keys for China
• Must use incorrect mathematical PRIME key for apostrophe
• Repeated hand coding to improve appearance
• Bypass only reduces flood, no system support for code solution

**Apostrophe Usage:**
• There is no selector for the apostrophe, defaults incorrect keyboard input method.
• The `<q>`  element for inline quotations (can be styled).
• The `<blockquote>` element for long quotations (can be styled).
• The `<cite>` element for source citations (can be styled).
• The `:lang` pseudo for browser control (could be combined with `:target`).

References:
• [Why Unicode Committee is wrong](https://tedclancy.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/which-unicode-character-should-represent-the-english-apostrophe-and-why-the-unicode-committee-is-very-wrong/)
• [Mozilla Developer, CSS, lang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang)
There's a MDN page with lang settings for dozens of keyboard layouts,
wherein interestingly, `:target` pseudo is mentioned, but inconclusive.
I also read CSS-Tricks.com/Forum post "Apostrophe Doesn't Render".
Also, developer.mozilla.org "CSS Fonts", and many other topics.

**3 important questions top of this thread**.

Comment: "Both HTML &prime; (CSS \2032) and HTML &apos; (CSS \0027) use the same glyph in every font installed by operating system." This is patently untrue.

Comment: Fontlab, etc, all of the typographic tools in my arsenal show that `&apos;` and `&prime;` use exactly the same glyph. Our apostrophe conundrum includes a cryptic global typographic restriction! Essentially, we must `style` a character interface. Or W3 can correct the mess.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has no mechanism for controlling/correcting the character used for apostrophes in English, let alone for all natural languages that use an apostrophe.

It's unclear what you mean by "publisher app" in #3, but at best you'd need a browser add-on to do this for you on the client side, and whatever it does to fix misrepresented apostrophes is going to involve more than just CSS.

Comment: Is this related to what is called "html escapes"? Are you saying some sort of `KeyboardEvent()` programming is required?<br> What about the reflexive nature of pseudo elements, specifically the inconclusive mention of `:target`, obviously in relation to `:before` and `:after` where the :lang pseudo is defining system language behaviors?<br> Maybe CSS can do more.

Comment: CSS just simply doesn't have the ability to replace arbitrary inline content. Nothing to do with character references - even if you typed ′ or ' directly instead of using &prime; or &apos; you could still not manipulate them with CSS. The content and quotes properties can *generate* additional content, but they can't alter what's already there. You don't need to listen for keyboard events, but you do need to alter the markup itself.

Comment: of `KeyboardEvent()` programming is required? What about the reflexive nature of pseudo elements, specifically the inconclusive mention of `:target`, obviously in relation to `:before` and `:after` where the :lang pseudo is defining system language behaviors? Maybe CSS can do more. e.g., selector a[href^=""] but an apostrophe attribute pattern.

Comment: Can CSS define and style some sort of 'content attribute' behavior? With some sort of OS support.

Comment: The :target pseudo is not relevant here - :target has to do with the URL fragment. The :lang() pseudo lets you apply different styles based on language, but it doesn't help you actually fix those apostrophes. CSS doesn't have a selector by content, but even if it did, you still wouldn't be able to alter the content of those elements after you've matched them.

Comment: keyword "match"... which is why I wish I had seen a Recommendation for 'apostrophe selector'. It would be the first punctuation ever to get that status, but how important is it: for example, how many hours were paid last year correcting apostrophes for digital publishing online? Likely a few hundred thousand any of us would appreciate! It's odd how apostrophe falls through the cracks. Wonder what else is pulling it down. Why is Israel's Raanana font the only font in North America that gives Apple devices a true apostrophe (but only using Hebrew). Concessions for all, please!

Comment: I need to think over URL fragment and browser language display. That and typographic prime bias' surely unintended outcome. Thank you.